# unknown char in output

Tags: c

When accepting input from the user, I sometimes get unknown characters:

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/833/capture1ec.jpg/]

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char plaintext[50];
    char arr[10]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'};
    char key[20];
    int plain=0,max1=0,max2=0;
    char chip[30][30];
    int z=0,i,j,k=0,c=0,a;
    char swap,temp; 
    printf("Enter key :");
    scanf("%[^\n]",key);

    for(i=0;key[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        max2++; 
    }

    printf("Enter plaintext :");
    scanf("%s",&plaintext);

    for( i = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++ ) 
    {
        plain++; 
    }

    if (plain%max2==0)
        max1=plain/max2;
    else
        max1=plain/max2+1;

    while (plaintext[k]!='\0')
    {        
        for (i=0;i<max1;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<max2;j++)
            {
                if (plaintext[k]!=NULL)
                {
                    chip[i][j]=plaintext[k];
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*printf("\n");
    for (i=0;i<max1;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<max2;j++)
        {
            printf("%c ",chip[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }*/

    for(i=0;i<max2;i++)
    {
        if(chip[max1-1][i]==NULL)
        {
            chip[max1-1][i]=arr[c];
            c++;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    /*for (i=0;i<max1;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<max2;j++)
        {
            printf("%c ",chip[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }*/

    for (i = 0 ; i < max2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < max2 ; j++)
        {
            if (key[i] < key[j]) 
            {
                swap = key[j];
                key[j] = key[i];
                key[i] = swap;

                for (a=0;a<max1;a++)
                {
                    temp=chip[a][j];
                    chip[a][j]=chip[a][i];
                    chip[a][i]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*printf("\n");
    for (i=0;i<max1;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<max2;j++)
        {
            printf("%c ",chip[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }*/
    for (i=0;i<max2;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<max1;j++)
        {
            if (chip[j][i]!=NULL)
                printf("%c ",chip[j][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is you didn't null terminate char arrays. Props to @root

Comment: What's with all the backslashes?

Comment: Please reduce this to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: For instance, you can write `plain = strlen(plaintext);` instead of `for( i = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++ ) 
    {
        plain++; 
    }`.

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to name your variables better. Instead of z,c,a,max1,max2,plain,etc. the code would be a lot clearer if the variables were named according to what they do or what data they hold. Also some comments in the code to explain what you are doing would go a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this before using `chip`.

```
#include <string.h>

...

char chip[30][30];
memset(chip, 0, 30 * 30);  // <- add this one

...
```

or simply

```
char chip[30][30] = {0};
```